# Can Metro make Java webservices interoperable with WCF even if Java lacks out parameter support?

Tags: java, wcf, interop, java-metro-framework, out-parameters

I have a WCF client that used to call a WCF method with an `out` parameter:

```
int SomeMethod(out int anotherReturnValue);
```

When reimplementing this method in a Java Webservice will I have to change this method contract? I heard that something called Metro made Java webservices interoperate with WCF, but I guess in this case I will have to change the contract. Is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Metro, You can annotate the out parameter with the `@WebParam` annotation.  Then define the parameter to a [`Holder`](http://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/jaxws-api/2.2/javax/xml/ws/Holder.html) for your original type.  For example:

```
int someMethod(@WebParam(name="anotherReturnValue", mode=Mode.OUT)
    Holder<Integer>anotherReturnValue);
```

See this article for more details: [WebService hints and tips](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-tip-jaxwsrpc3/#N101B3)